# Translation of "un stratège dans l’âme"

Tags: traduction, anglais

> Un stratège dans l’âme

Is this an official term in gambling, or a French expression? How should it be translated to English?

Original sentence is

> Êtes-vous plutôt un stratège dans l'âme ?

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a little more context than just the expression the question is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Le maréchal Joukov était un stratège dans l'âme" could be translated by

Marshal Joukov was a born-strategist. Of course the invoked soul has disappeared in the translation, but I would say that born-strategist is the standard way to say something like this in English.

Comment: *"Was a strategist at heart"* is an English idiom whose literal meaning is closer to *dans l'âme*.

Answer (score 7):

"***dans l'âme***" is a French expression meaning that the quality in question is part of the deepest nature of the subject.

"***Mozart était musicien dans l'âme***" means that music was deeply part of Mozart's nature.